# Filter out all dates that aren't the second to latest date in the month?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Need help creating a filter that only returns the latest date of the month for every month. For instance, if this is my table, I want to return the one below.

My table

| Date |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | x ... |
| 1/8/2022 | x ... |
| 2/5/2022 | x ... |
| 2/28/2022 | x ... |
| 3/5/2022 | x ... |
| 3/5/2022 | x ... |
| 4/10/2022 | x ... |
| 4/15/2022 | x ... |
| 4/28/2022 | x ... |

| Date |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1/8/2022 | x ... |
| 2/28/2022 | x ... |
| 3/5/2022 | x ... |
| 3/5/2022 | x ... |
| 4/28/2022 | x ... |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MyTable looking like this

[image]

you can use this **calculated table** formula

```
Last Date Rows in Month = 
VAR tbl =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
            'MyTable',
            'MyTable'[Date].[Year],
            'MyTable'[Date].[Month],
            "maxDates", MAX('MyTable'[Date])
        ),
        "maxDates", [maxDates]
    )
RETURN  
    FILTER(
        'MyTable',
        'MyTable'[Date] in tbl
    )
```

to get the following result

[image]